# Search a content type based on certain criteria

Tags: nodes, search

I am faced with a challenge for my company's new website.  We are using Drupal 7 and here is the situation:  We have approximately 250 doctors in our group and I am tasked with creating a custom search page where users can search our doctors based on certain criteria (e.g. specialty, gender, location, etc.).

I have created a content type of "doctor" and entered all of the physician data that will be needed.  My question is:  how is the best way to go about setting up the search that I want to give my visitors?  I would assume that I need to restrict a search based on content type, but how can I throw the additional search parameters in there?  Are there some modules that give very granular options like I'm looking for, or am I looking at having to create and code a custom module??

I'm a little lost and any direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make use of the [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views)  to create the functionality you are looking for.

- Create a new display of type page
- Then select show content of type [Your content type]
- Add fields you want users to be able to search on
- Create filters and expose the filters

Comment: Thanks @4life.  I will give it a go and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

i am sure this is so easy option rather than generating a view .

```
/** nice snipet to restrict search content type **/

   function mymodule_search_query_search_node_alter(&$query) {
   $query->condition('n.type', 'article', '=');
   }
```